# Route vs. Resource

Tags: haskell, yesod

In the Yesod book it is state at Part I. Basics, Chapter 3. Basics, Section Routing (Second Edition):

```hs
mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]
```

> In other words, the preceding code simply creates a route [...] called `HomeR`. [...]. We call `HomeR` a resource, which is where the R suffix comes from.

This is just about wording, I know, but I would like to understand if `HomeR` is a *route* or a *resource*.
(please don't say "both").

Comment: I think the root is `/`, but it it named using the type `HomeR`, which is a resource. Or possibly the resource is the handler, which corresponds to a type-safe URL. I'm not too sure though since T haven't found the distinction to be too important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is based off [this Yesod documentation page](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers).

The route `/ HomeR GET` is made up of

1. the resource pattern `/`
2. the resource name `HomeR`
3. the `GET` handler

As far as I can tell, the resource name is unique to each route, so the documentation takes the shortcut of referring to "the route with resource name `X`" as "the route `X`".

So the answer is: `HomeR` is a resource, and `HomeR` is the route with resource name `HomeR`. (Both, in other words).